# Explanation on the usage of Lombok's @NonNull

Tags: java, lombok

What is the difference in the usage of @NonNull in the following two cases:

Case 1:

```
class MyClass {
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @Builder
    MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Case 2:

```
class MyClass {
    private String name;

    @Builder
    MyClass(@NonNull String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Why don't compile both versions and inspect the byte code coming out of the compiler?! Always try to be creative to find answers yourself. You learn much more from making experiments compared to asking for explanations. Try first, ask later.

Comment: Even easier: Use `delombok` to print the source code Lombok generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, experimenting yourself with delombok is worth more than asking. However, Case 1 is interesting because of `MyClass(null).name` simply returning `null`.

You may think that lombok doesn't work, but it's just that it does not rewrite your manually written constructor. It only guarantee that it itself never assigns `null` to a field marked with `@NonNull`. What you do yourself is your responsibility.

You shouldn't expect too much from Lombok. It's a great tool making my code maybe 30% shorter, but as with every tool you have to know its limits.